# How to assign values to all the elements of matrix in a loop

Tags: matlab

I am using wine-dataset(red) from UCI. I have to split it in 70-15-15. Following is my code

```
valSet = zeros(240, 12);
valTest=zeros(240, 1);
 for i=1201:1441
     for j=1:12
         valSet(i,j)=features(i,j);

     end
 end
 for i=1201:1441

         valTest(i,13)=features(i,13);

 end
```

Now the elements from 1201 to 1441 are included invalidation set. valSet has all the attribute values (12 attributes) and valTest has the last column (quality) which is the target value.
In the above code I am assigning values from features array to valSet and valTest array. But when I open these matrices in workspace, all the values are zero. I can't identify what the problem is.

Comment: All the values are zero, or all the values from 1:1200 are zero? The first value that you set in `valSet` is `valSet(1201,1)`. Change your code to  `valSet(i-1200,j)`

Comment: @AnderBiguri peculiar point is that in the workspace size of valSet matrix is 1441,11

Comment: Yes.... Because the last value you set is `valSet(1441,12)`.... Look at your code.

Comment: it worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first value that you set in `valSet` is `valSet(1201,1)`. Change your code to `valSet(i-1200,j)`.

Matlab will otherwise fill all previous values with zeroes.